# List of all the people that could have been Moshiach

Tags: sources-mekorot, messiah, messianic-redemption, king-hezekiah

I've been doing some research on the topic of "who could have been Moshiach based on Chazal" an example of one such person is Chizkiyahu Hamelech as it says in [Sanhedrin 94.](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin_94a.4)

If anyone knows any names with a source, please post it here.

Thank You.

Comment: There have probably been hundreds or thousands over the years, just nobody knew who they were.

Comment: Are you counting people like Bar Kochba who were thought to be Mashiach but were later disqualified, or only people about whom Chazal day would have actually been Mashiach had we been worthy?

Comment: @DonielF both, as long as you can provide a source.

Comment: @user18660 How far are you willing to push the Bar Kochba-type category? Does Shabesai Tzvi count, since many Rabbanim thought he was actually Mashiach?

Comment: Does this include the section in the gemara where they argue over the moshiach's name?

Comment: To VTCers: How exactly is this too broad?